# Convert character to GPS datetime with R

Tags: r, datetime, char

I know this question was asked multiple times but the data was different in each case. Here is my data

```
> starttime
[1] "2015-12-05T09:57:47.391Z"
> endtime
[1] "2015-12-05T10:08:47.135Z"
```

The problem is the ".391Z" and ".135Z" at the end. I actually don't know what it is and feel a bit insecure to cut them off from the string. If I cut them off, I could easily use strptime to convert

```
> starttime
[1] "2015-12-05T09:57:47"
> endtime
[1] "2015-12-05T10:08:47"
> strptime(starttime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-12-05 09:57:47 GMT"
> strptime(endtime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-12-05 10:08:47 GMT"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think Z means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), in which case, provided you're using GMT, you might be okay. (Maybe be careful around GMT and BST)

Comment: You make make use of those fractional seconds like this: `options(digits.secs=3); as.POSIXct("2015-12-05T09:57:47.391Z", format="%FT%H:%M:%OS")`.